# How do disable "Go to declaration" when long press on a Mac

Tags: android-studio-electric-eel

When I long press a highlighted area or keyword in Android Studio (Electric Eel) on my Mac, it automatically jumps me to the declaration, which is ***extremely*** annoying, as I invoke this feature by accident 99.9% of the time. As such, I would like to disable it.

However, I couldn't find any information on how to disable this feature for AS Electric Eel. Does anyone know how to disable it? Thanks!